# docker logs within a bash script doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, docker, containers

I'm experimenting a weird behaviour of Docker in a bash script.
Let's see these two examples:

```
logs-are-showed() {
     docker rm -f mybash &>/dev/null
     docker run -it --rm -d --name mybash bash -c "echo hello; tail -f /dev/null"
     docker logs mybash
}

# usage:
# $ localtunnel 8080
localtunnel() {
     docker rm -f localtunnel &>/dev/null
     docker run -it -d --network host --name localtunnel efrecon/localtunnel --port $1
     docker logs localtunnel
}
```

In the first function ***logs-are-showed*** the command `docker logs` returns me the logs of the container *mybash*

In the second function ***localtunnel*** the command `docker logs` doesn't return me anything.
After having called the ***localtunnel*** function, if I ask for the container logs from **outside the script**, it shows me the logs correctly.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `doesn't return me anything` So there are no logs in that container. `if I ask for the container logs from outside the script` If you ask for logs _manually after some time_ then there are logs. Add a `sleep 20` before logs - does it help?

Comment: yeah! You're right! ahahha I was struggling but it was pretty simple! Thanks! You wanna write the answer so I check as the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processes take time to react. They may be no logs right after starting a process - it has not written anything *yet*. Wait a bit.